# Problema com a lógica relacional SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, lógica, tabela-banco-de-dados

Considerando esse esquema

```
CREATE TABLE bra_ocorrencias (
    estado varchar2(2),
    genero varchar2(1),
    ano number,
    nome varchar2(30),
    num_ocorrencia number
);
```

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que me retorna **o nome mais registrado por mulheres no estado de SP, MG e RJ no período de 2006 a 2012**. Então eu escrevi dessa forma

```
SELECT nome
FROM bra_ocorrencias 
WHERE genero LIKE 'F'
AND estado LIKE 'SP' AND estado LIKE 'MG' AND estado LIKE 'RJ'
AND ano BETWEEN 2006 AND 2012
```

A consulta não possui erros de sintaxe, ela me retorna resultados porém não de acordo com a lógica proposta, alguém consegue ver o erro na lógica relacional da minha sintaxe em relação a regra de consulta dada acima?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja a query com comentários:

```
WHERE genero LIKE 'F'
```

LIKE é usado com '%', assim por exemplo 'F%' o que significa "qualquer gênero iniciado por F", o '%" ao final significa "qualquer coisa". Se quiser uma busca com o valor exato, melhor usar `=`. Fica assim:

```
WHERE genero = 'F'
```

No estado:

```
AND estado LIKE 'SP' AND estado LIKE 'MG' AND estado LIKE 'RJ'
```

usando o operador `AND` não vai funcionar porque um estado **NUNCA** vai ser, ao mesmo tempo (AND) igual a SP, MG e RJ, apenas um deles por vez, então deve usar o operador `OR` (um ou outro dos estados), assim:

```
AND (estado = 'SP' OR estado = 'MG' OR estado = 'RJ')
```

Ou também poderia usar o operador `IN` para usar uma lista de valores:

```
 AND estado IN ('SP','MG','RJ')
```

Query completa

```
SELECT nome
  FROM bra_ocorrencias 
 WHERE genero = 'F'
   AND (estado='SP' OR estado='MG' OR estado='RJ')
   AND ano BETWEEN 2006 AND 2012
```

Comment: PERFEITO. Você poderia só me ajudar a incrementar na tua Query o retorno de uma única linha? ou seja, a ocorrência mais registrada, acredito que seja um max(num_ocorrencia)

Comment: Se usar o max(num_ocorrencia) não vai poder retornar o nome, porque quando usa uma função de agração (max), todos os campos tem de ser agregados (com funções), ou estarem no `group by`. No seu caso deve funcionar ordenar por num_ocorrencias e pegar o primeiro. Coloque isso no final da query: `ORDER BY num_ocorrencias DESC  LIMIT 1`

Comment: Faça um teste, pois o LIMIT pode limitar o resultado antes de todo o ORDER BY estar completo

Answer (score 3):

SQL corrigido:

```
SELECT nome
FROM bra_ocorrencias 
WHERE genero = 'F'
AND (estado = 'SP' OR estado = 'MG' OR estado = 'RJ')
AND ano BETWEEN 2006 AND 2012
```

Alterei para trazer apenas os estados que quer usando `OR` e tirei o `LIKE`, pois não vi necessidade dele.

Troquei o `AND` por `OR` pois na consulta original você está tentando pegar os registros de estados que são MG, SP e RJ **ao mesmo tempo**. Não fazia sentido para o seu problema. O que você quer são os estados que podem ser **qualquer um** destes.

Você pode adicionar um `ORDER BY` ao final para ordenar por ocorrências:

```
ORDER BY num_ocorrencia DESC
```

Comment: Existe uma diferença significativa entre o uso do '=' pro LIKE?

Comment: @RafaelBrito `LIKE` é útil quando você quer procurar por um padrão ao invés do valor exato. Ex: `estado LIKE 'S%'` busca todos os estados que começam com `S`. Como no seu caso você está buscando os valores exatos (SP, MG, RJ), não há necessidade de usar `LIKE`.